# Using Get-ChildItem -Exclude or -Include returns nothing

Tags: powershell, wildcard, glob, powershell-4.0

I have a list in my C: directory that has many files. If I try to run an `-Exclude` on it, I get no returns. Same with `-Include`. If I use `-Filter`, it returns what I expected to get back. Am I not understanding what it should be doing?

Here is an example of what I am running and getting nothing:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C: -Exclude "*.txt"
```

I get nothing back. If I run

```
Get-Childitem -filter "*.txt"
```

I get this back:

```
  Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                               
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                               
-a----        11/7/2007   8:00 AM          17734 eula.1028.txt                                                                      
-a----        11/7/2007   8:00 AM          17734 eula.1031.txt                                                                      
-a----        11/7/2007   8:00 AM          10134 eula.1033.txt                                                                      
-a----        11/7/2007   8:00 AM          17734 eula.1036.txt                                                                      
-a----        11/7/2007   8:00 AM          17734 eula.1040.txt                                                                      
-a----        11/7/2007   8:00 AM            118 eula.1041.txt                                                                      
-a----        11/7/2007   8:00 AM          17734 eula.1042.txt                                                                      
-a----        11/7/2007   8:00 AM          17734 eula.2052.txt                                                                      
-a----        11/7/2007   8:00 AM          17734 eula.3082.txt                                                                      
               7/7/2016   8:50 AM             93 HaxLogs.txt                                                                        
-a----         7/8/2016   8:30 AM              0 Test.txt
```

Comment: For me it works without a problem, but have you tried not using quotation marks for the extension too? Like `Get-ChildItem -Path C: -Exclude *.txt` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\*" -Include "*.txt"
```

This example, of how `-Include` should work, will give you the results you were expecting.  Note that I provided a wildcard in the path parameter as well, to explicitly define the path as "any file in the root C:" as opposed to "C:" itself.

Source:
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849800.aspx

Example 3 from this link, in case it goes defunct (note the wildcard in path here, as well):

```
C:\> Get-ChildItem –Path "C:\Windows\Logs\*" -Include "*.txt" -Exclude "A*"
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason the wildcard in the path does work.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that drives me mad: when APIs/commands behave in different ways based on input. Of course, that SHOULD happen but what I mean specifically is like in this case. When you pass in a path alone it presumes the wildcard `*`. When you add `-Include` or `-Exclude` it stops making that presumption and the docs don't say this. More importantly, the command is CALLED `Get-ChildItem`. It should be getting CHILD items. The wildcard should be unnecessary in all cases.

Comment: Wow. Apparently adding a wildcard to the path made everything work. that was super confusing

Answer (score 46):

To summarize and complement [gravity's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38269316/45375) and [Brian Reynolds's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38274869/45375) helpful answers:

There are two distinct problems with your approach:

- Targeting `C:` probably doesn't (always) do what you want, because **`C:` refers to *whatever happens to be the current location* (working dir.) on drive C: at the moment.**

  - To target the *root folder* of drive C:, you must use `C:\`, which I'll assume is what you meant in the remainder of this answer.
- Using the **`-Exclude` (and also `-Include`) parameter with neither `-Recurse` nor a `-Path` value of `*` or ending in `\*` often yields NO results.** Unexpected? Indeed - see below for more.

  - Thus, `Get-Item -Path C:\* -Exclude *.txt` - note the switch from `Get-ChildItem` to `Get-Item` and the `*` after `C:\` - is needed to make your command work for the items located *directly* in `C:\` only.

---

#### Background information:

**Using the provider-native `-Filter` parameter is generally preferable to `-Include`**, because:

- it is much faster than `-Include` due to the provider itself performing the filtering *at the source*, as opposed to letting PowerShell apply the filter *later*, after all objects have been received.
- it doesn't require you to switch to `Get-Item` and append `\*` to the `-Path` parameter value.

  - `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Filter *.txt` works fine for matching all `*.txt` files in the root directory of C:, for instance.

That said, there are **caveats**:

- *The wildcard pattern language supported by `-Filter` has fewer features than PowerShell's - notably, it doesn't support character sets/ranges such as `[0-9]` - may unexpectedly match short (8.3) filenames, and has other legacy quirks* - see [this well-researched answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17739503/45375) for the gory details.
- `-Filter` supports only a *single* pattern, whereas `-Include` supports multiple ones (an *array* of patterns).

Unfortunately, **`-Filter` is always a *positive* (inclusionary) filter** and therefore cannot be used to provide the functionality of `-Exclude`.

---

#### The implementation of `-Include` / `-Exclude` with `Get-ChildItem` is unintuitive and has pitfalls:

<sup>**Side note**: if you only use *one* `-Include` pattern (as opposed to `-Exclude`), it's easier to append the pattern directly to the `-Path` argument; e.g.: `Get-ChildItem C:\*.txt`</sup>

**tl;dr**:

**To get predictable behavior with `-Include` / `-Exclude` if you're *not* also using `-Recurse`** (if you *are* using `-Recurse` this workaround is *not* needed):

```bash
# IMPORTANT: Workaround isn't needed if you're using -Recurse.
#   * "\*" was appended to the input path
#   * Get-*ChildItem* was switched to Get-*Item*
Get-Item C:\path\to\* -Include ...
Get-Item C:\path\to\* -Exclude ...
```

In **PowerShell (Core) v7+**, *if* your input paths are *literal* ones, you can alternatively use `Get-ChildItem` with `-LiteralPath` rather than (possibly positionally implied) `-Path` (use `.` for the current dir.):

```bash
# IMPORTANT: Works in PowerShell (Core) only.
#            Note the use of -LiteralPath.
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath C:\path\to -Include ...
Get-ChildItem -Literalpath C:\path\to -Exclude ...
```

---

- There's an **outright *bug* in *Windows PowerShell*** where, when `-LiteralPath` is used, `-Include` / `-Exclude` are *quietly ignored*. This has been fixed in *PowerShell (Core)* as of (at least) v7.0 (and it's fair to assume that it will *not* be fixed in Windows PowerShell, which will only receive *critical* fixes going forward).
- **`-Include` and `-Exclude` do not work as one would intuitively expect**, which is the subject of [GitHub issue #3304](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3304):

  - `-Include` and `-Exclude` modify the *leaf* (last) path component of the `-Path` argument, i.e. file or directory *names* in the case of file-system paths.
  - That means that **the patterns are *first* applied to the leaf component of the specified *folder path itself*, *before* getting applied to the *child items***, if at all.
  - If the input path doesn't end in `\*` and `-Recurse` is not specified, the implications are as follows:

    - `-Include`: If the input path's last path component does *not* match the `-Include` pattern(s), the input path *itself* is excluded (not included), and the path's *child* items are never looked at - nothing is output.
    - `-Exclude`: Analogously, if the input path's last path component *does* match the `-Exclude` pattern(s), the input path *itself* is excluded, and the path's *child* items are never looked at - nothing is output.

      - **Targeting a *root* directory** - e.g., `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Exclude Windows`) appears to be **broken altogether as of v7.0**: it either produces no output at all, or fails on Unix-like platforms, both with `-Include` and `-Exclude`, irrespective of the patterns used - see [GitHub issue #11649](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11649).
    - As stated, **the problem doesn't surface if `-Recurse` is used**, because that *forces* descending into the input path's subtree, even if the input path itself is not included / excluded.
- **Unless `-Recurse` is needed, the only way to get expected behavior** is to replace
  `Get-ChildItem C:\path\to -Include / -Exclude` with
  **`Get-Item C:\path\to\* -Include / -Exclude`** - note the use of *`Get-Item`* instead of `Get-ChildItem`, and that `\*` was appended to the `-Path` argument.

  - By contrast, if you use `Get-ChildItem *` in combination with `-Exclude` and there are *directories* among the non-excluded items, `Get-ChildItem` will unexpectedly output *their contents instead*; this does *not* happen with `-Include` and generally doesn't happen with subdirectory matches *by a wildcard expression* (`-Path` argument and/or `-Filter` argument).
- A **summary of the problems** as of PowerShell 7.2:

  - [GitHub issue #3304](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3304) (discussed above): counterintuitive application of `-Include` / `-Exclude` patterns only to the input themselves rather than to their children.
  - [GitHub issue #11649](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11649): `Get-ChildItem -Path <rootPath> -Exclude <anyPattern>` unexpectedly produces *no* output (even though *nothing should be excluded*, given that the exclusion pattern is normally applied to the input paths, such as `/` or `c:\`).
  - [GitHub issue #9126](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9126): `-Include` / `-Exclude` unexpectedly follow symlinks when `-Recurse` is used.
  - [GitHub issue #8662](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8662): performance problem: `-Include` / `-Exclude` are slower(!) than after-the-fact filtering with `Where-Object`.
  - A related *feature request* is [GitHub issue #15159](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15159), which suggests introducing the ability to exclude subfolder *subtrees* (as opposed to just excluding the items matching the patterns themselves, but not their children), with a new parameter such as `-ExcludeSubtree`.

---

#### Examples: problematic uses of `-Include` / `-Exclude`

Note: To make all commands below work as one would intuitively expect, replace `Get-ChildItem C:\Windows` with `Get-Item C:\Windows\*` - note the use of a different cmdlet, `Get-Item`, and the appended `\*`.

```bash
# HAPPENS TO WORK, BUT IS NOT ROBUST:
# Matches all w* items *inside* C:\Windows, but
# ONLY because w* happens to match 'Windows' - the last input
# path component - too.
Get-ChildItem C:\Windows -Include w*

# HAPPENS TO WORK, BUT IS NOT ROBUST:
# Matches all items whose names *don't* start with a-v *inside* C:\Windows, but
# ONLY because [a-v]* happens not to exclude 'Windows' - the last input
# path component - too.
Get-ChildItem C:\Windows -Exclude [a-v]*


# OUTPUTS NOTHING:
# Because t* doesn't match 'Windows', the child items of 
# 'C:\Windows' are not considered.
Get-ChildItem C:\Windows -Include t*

# OUTPUTS NOTHING:
# Because w* matches 'Windows', it is excluded, and
# the child items of 'C:\Windows' are not considered.     
Get-ChildItem C:\Windows -Exclude w*
```

Comment: Holy moly that's a thorough incorporation of all of the different hang-ups this had!  Way to really dig deep into the reasoning!  :)  Is there somewhere that you found this, or did you research it on your own?

Comment: This is broken beyond all belief. It's literally saying that -Include/-Exclude are known to just be silently ignored; therefore they're unreliable. It would be outright dangerous to write a script to delete child directories with an -Exclude option, because it could delete them. This a huge problem, because the Remove-Item documentation says its -Recurse parameter is also 'known to not work', and suggests using Get-ChildItem to pipe it to the command as a workaround. But Get-ChildItem is also clearly broken! What a mess.

Comment: P.S., @Triynko: A similarly potentially destructive problem is discussed in [GitHub issue #5699](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5699).

Comment: Small correction, @Triynko: `-Include` / `-Exclude` aren't _ignored_ - they are just not applied in the way one would expect: they are inappropriately applied to the _input_ path(s) (first) rather than (only) to _their child items_, and the resulting, seemingly unpredictable behavior is arguably even worse than just ignoring. As for the warnings in the `Remove-Item` help topic re `-Recurse` / combining `-Recurse` with `-Include`: Let's try to get those clarified / updated / removed: see [Github docs issue #8134](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/8134).

Comment: I was confronted with the unique problem of getting all files and folders with no dot in their name. Apparently, `-Filter *.` was the solution, despite the fact that this parameter is supposed to be inclusionary. Truly dark magic.

Comment: @AgentRev, yes, that's counterintuitive, but it isn't PowerShell's fault: the `-Filter` argument is generally provider-specific, which for file-system paths means that it's the underlying WinAPI that handles the wildcard matching, which has a lot of legacy quirks, such as the one you mention  - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60171419/45375).

Answer (score 2):

Using 'C:' with no slash after it is the reason you're not getting the results you want. This is being interpreted as a relative path to the current directory instead of the root of the C drive. (See: [Path with no slash after drive letter and colon - what does it point to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23955968/path-with-no-slash-after-drive-letter-and-colon-what-does-it-point-to))

If you use 'C:\' instead it should work as expected.

Edit: My mistake; I was responding specifically to the examples which only use '-exclude'.

Comment: Actually, it does not.  Try it yourself.  `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\" -Include "*.txt"` yields no results, whereas, `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\*" -Include "*.txt"` shows me all of the files extensions with `.txt`

Comment: Yes, I get no results unless I add the *. after C:\. I'm not sure why because I am at location C: and if I use Get-ChildItem C: or Get-ChildItem C:\ I get all the files back. It appears only -Include and -Exclude do this for me. I'm running PSVersion - 5.0.10586.122

Comment: It is (unfortunately) true that appending \* in the absence of -Recurse is needed with -Include / -Exclude), but this answer makes a good point about `C:` vs. `C:\ `

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug (because the string version of the parent properties is empty string?).  With subdirectories, it works fine:

```
get-childitem c:\windows -directory -exclude *.dll
```

You can specify the root directory in a different way, and get a strange error message:

```
get-childitem Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\ -exclude *.txt

get-childitem : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is not valid. Change the value of the "path" argument and run the operation again.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-childitem Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\ -exclude wind ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Or, in osx:

```
get-childitem / -directory -exclude *.txt

get-childitem : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is not valid. Change the value of the "path" argument and run the operation again.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-childitem / -directory -exclude var
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

This is a workaround for powershell 6 and above:

```
get-item c:\ | get-childitem -exclude *.txt
```