# Filtering child folders with Get-ChildItem -Exclude using a dynamically constructed array of exclusion patterns

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, subdirectory, get-childitem, glob

I have following folders inside the "clients" directory

```
Arizona
California
Connecticut
Default
Delaware
Florida
Hawaii
Idaho
Iowa
Maine
```

I have an array and it has following items:

```
Write-Host "Printing the array " 
$ExcludeArray

Output----
"Arizona",
"California"
```

I'm trying to list the folders inside `C:\Users\santhu\Desktop\Clients` and exclude the folders in my `$ExcludeArray` array using following command.

```
Get-Childitem C:\Users\santhu\Desktop\Clients -Force -Exclude $ExcludeArray
```

It seems the exclude is not working as expected. I believe the reason could be the items in `$ExcludeArray` are not in same line. Can someone please suggest me if there is any way to convert them to same line and filter the folders?
FYI: the `$ExcludeArray` items are not static. I cannot write something like `$ExcludeArray = "Arizona","California"`. I'm expecting following output.

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                       
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                                                                                                       
d----         3/20/2017  12:15 PM            Connecticut                                                                
d----         3/20/2017  12:15 PM            Default                                                                    
d----         3/20/2017  12:15 PM            Delaware                                                                   
d----         3/20/2017  12:15 PM            Florida                                                                    
d----         3/20/2017  12:15 PM            Hawaii                                                                     
d----         3/20/2017  12:15 PM            Idaho                                                                      
d----         3/20/2017  12:15 PM            Iowa                                                                       
d----         3/20/2017  12:15 PM            Maine                                                                      
d----         3/20/2017  12:15 PM            Minnesota
```

Comment: `-Recurse` should also have worked for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-Childitem C:\Users\santhu\Desktop\Clients\* -Force -Exclude $ExcludeArray
```

The exclude and include switch is a bit tricky here. It works on the last mentioned path. So wildcard should do your work. Make sure you are not having any double quotes inside the array.

Comment: removing double quotes inside the array worked. Thanks.

Comment: Good to hear that

Comment: I initially thought that was the solution too, but this will output the _contents_ of non-excluded directories, not the directories themselves.

Answer (score 1):

- We now know that your **primary problem** was the **content of `$ExcludeArray`**, your dynamically constructed array of strings (exclusion patterns), whose elements either mistakenly had *embedded* `"` chars. (E.g, `"Arizona"` instead of just `Arizona`) or, possibly, `$ExcludeArray` mistakenly contained a single, multi-line string rather than array.

  - To read lines from a file into the elements of a string array, all that is needed is `$ExcludeArray = Get-Content file`
  - If the file's lines contain strings enclosed in `"` chars. possibly terminated with `,` (e.g., `"Arizona",` or `"California"`, you need to trim those characters:
    `$ExcludeArray = (Get-Content File) -replace '^"(.*)",?', '$1'`
- **With a correctly constructed array your original command *does* work, but *only* if none of the patterns in `$ExcludeArray` match the *last component* of the *input path* - `Client`, in this case.**

  - In other words: `-Exclude` and `-Include` are perhaps unexpectedly compared to the *input path*'s last path component (the file name in case of a file path, the directory name in case of a directory path).
  - In the case of `Get-ChildItem`, that matching against the *parent* directory name happens *before* the names of the *child* items (the items *inside* the directory) are matched, and if the parent doesn't match, the child items aren't even looked at, and nothing is output.
  - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375) of mine explains this unintuitive behavior in more detail.

It is therefore better to find a **generally robust idiom** that solves your problem, where **matching against the parent directory's name is avoided**:

- Switch from `Get-ChildItem` to `Get-Item`.
- Append `\*` to your input path.

Specifically:

```
Get-Item C:\Users\santhu\Desktop\Clients\* -Force -Exclude $ExcludeArray
```

By contrast, if you append `\*` but stick with `Get-*Child*Item`, as in [Ranadip Dutta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43052108/45375), your command will behave differently: You'll get the *contents* (child items) of any child directories that aren't excluded, not the *directories themselves*.

Comment: @mklement0- First of all thanks a lot for the response. I agree. I will try this too.

Comment: @mahesh: My pleasure; I felt I needed to post my own answer, because Ranadip's answer mistakenly solves a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

this code work on my pc

```
$ExcludeArray="Arizona","California"
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\santhu\Desktop\Clients" -Exclude $ExcludeArray
```

or like this

```
$ExcludeArray="Arizona","California"
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\santhu\Desktop\Clients" | where Name -notin $ExcludeArray
```

Comment: The 1st command _happens_ to work _in this case_, but is not generally robust - consider what happens when you use `Get-ChildItem C:\Windows -Exclude W*` - if one of the exclusion patterns happens to match the _parent_ directory's name, you get no results at all.
Aside from using PSv3+ syntax, the 2nd command is a viable alternative, albeit slower than a (robust) `-Exclude`-based solution.