# Powershell script to copy and sequentially rename files

Tags: powershell

I am writing a PS script that takes a flattened directory structure, finds the pdfs, and copies them to a renamed folder with a sequential name, ie, 1.pdf, 2.pdf, etc.  What I want to do is make this accommodate nested directories in the Location, but I am a bit of a novice with PS and don't know how to do this while maintaining the count variable.

Here is what I have:

```
Set-Location -path "C:\Users\mmcintyre\Desktop\test pdfs"
Get-ChildItem *.pdf | 
ForEach-Object  -Begin { $count = 1 } -Process { 
    Copy-Item -LiteralPath $_ -Destination ".\renamed\$count.pdf"; 
    Write-Host "Renamed $($_.fullname) to $count.pdf"
    $count++ 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:  As I was on Powershell =< 2.0, I needed to use the following in addition to the Recurse:

`Get-ChildItem -Path .\* -Include *.pdf -Recurse |`

which works now.  Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Use the `-Recurse` parameter of `Get-ChildItem`

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I figured out the problem, as I was trying Recurse on that get-ChildItem.  I've posted what I found in an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified PSv2+ solution:

```
$countRef = [ref] 0
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf -Recurse |
  Copy-Item -WhatIf -Destination { '.\renamed\{0}.pdf' -f ++$countRef.Value }
```

<sup>`-WhatIf` previews the copy operations; remove it to perform actual copying.</sup>

- As in your solution, `-Recurse` is needed to traverse the entire directory subtree.
- `-Filter` is used instead of `-Include`, because it is:

  - noticeably faster
  - and doesn't require the workaround of passing `.\*` as the input path (because `-Include` patterns only apply to the last path component *as specified*)
  - An explanation can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375) of mine.
  - Also note that in PSv3+ you could also use `Get-ChildItem *.pdf -Recurse`, in which case `*.pdf` implicitly binds to the `-Path` parameter; however, as you've noticed, that doesn't work in PSv2 (but using `-Filter` does).
- A *script-block parameter* is used to specify the destination path, which obviates the need for a slower `ForEach-Object` call.

  - Note the need for a `[ref]` instance as the sequence-number value holder, and the need to access the value via `.Count`.

    - This is necessary, because the script block passed to `-Destination` runs in a *child* variable scope rather than in the caller's scope (the way script blocks passed to `ForEach-Object` do); this discrepancy is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7157).