# Getting -Filter or -Include values from .txt file

Tags: powershell

I have a txt file with filenames (i.e `01234.tif`) that I would like to use to filter a Get-ChildItem cmdlet. I did

```
$filenames = Get-Content filenames.txt
```

(also tried with `| Out-String`)

and then

```
Get-ChildItem . -Include $filenames | ForEach {if (!(Test-Path -Path ./jpeg/$_.Basename+".jpg")) {some imagemagick processing}}
```

but it does nothing. Funny part is that it works for excluding, since

```
Get-ChildItem . -Exclude $filenames > exclude.txt
```

writes the expected amount of lines. What am I missing here?

```
Get-Content filenames.txt | ForEach (path test) {imagemagick}
```

runs but copies all items, so either the path checking or Get-Content isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps surprisingly, `-Include` (also `-Exclude`) is *first* applied to the names of the (possibly wildcard-expanded) *input* path(s), and - only in case of match - *then* to the *children* of directories targeted by literal path(s).
The problem does *not* arise if `-Recurse` is also used.
See [GitHub issue #3304](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3304).

Therefore, use `Get-Item *` (`Get-ChildItem *` would work too, but only with `-Include`, not (properly) with `-Exclude`), so that the names of the *child items* are matched against the `-Include` patterns:

```
Get-Item * -Include (Get-Content filenames.txt)
```

Add `-Force` to also include *hidden* items.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375) for a detailed discussion of the pitfalls of `-Include` and `-Exclude`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. Do you happen to spot any inconsistency in my ```Test-Path``` usage? It is still overwriting all files at destination... Does ```BaseName``` work only with full path objects?

Comment: @MartimPassos: Try `"./jpeg/$($_.Basename).jpg"` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375