# pwsh dir not working with wildcard when using -include

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

Currently when using powershell on linux and test deleting some files

`dir Desktop\* -include psmyfolder*`  ( This doesn't seem to work at all)

`dir Desktop -include psmyfolder* -recurse` (However this works)

I understand that the -filter parameter is better as it's native and more efficient.
However I am trying to go through a tutorial and was under the impression that the wildcard for Desktop* should work as well.

Comment: itnoob, with the disclaimer that it is my own answer I'm pointing to, I believe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375) tells the whole sordid tale.