# Adding _ at the end of every file name of 3 type of extension in a folder

Tags: powershell

How could I modify name of every file by adding `_` before the filename extension in a `Get-ChildItem -Include` without calling 3 times a `Foreach`.

My script works, but I would like to simplify it by using `-Include` and not `-Filter`.

```
function renommer_fichier {

    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\mestp\mesFichiers -Filter *.jpg
        Foreach ($file in $files)
        {
            $file | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.jpg', '_.jpg' }
        }
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\mestp\mesFichiers -Filter *.mp3
        Foreach ($file in $files)
        {
            $file | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.mp3', '_.mp3' }
        }
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\mestp\mesFichiers -Filter *.mpeg
        Foreach ($file in $files)
        {
            $file | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.mpeg', '_.mpeg' }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Unfortunately, the `-Include` parameter - which supports specifying *multiple* patterns - doesn't work as one would intuitively expect:

  - Use [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) instead of [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) and append `\*` to the input path to make `-Include` work as intended.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375) for background information.
- Use the `.BaseName` and `.Extension` properties in the [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) you're passing to [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) to facilitate inserting `_` before the filename extension.

```bash
Get-Item -Path C:\mestp\mesFichiers\* -Include *.jpg, *mp3, *.mpeg |
  Rename-Item -WhatIf -NewName { $_.BaseName + '_' + $_.Extension }
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Comment: I'm sorry for my rookie question but as I search on web I cant figure out what is $_ meaning clearly

Comment: @G0Y1M `$_` is  what PowerShell calls an _automatic variable_ and, in a pipeline / delay-bind script-block context, it represents the current pipeline  input  object. See the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_)

Comment: Ok so $_ only works as an automatic return variable following the use of a Pipe. If I perform a ForEach $File in $Files each value of $File remains $File and can't be invoked by the $_ variable

Comment: @G0Y1M: Yes, even though `foreach` is - confusingly - also an _alias_ for the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) _cmdlet_ - where `$_` must be used - it is distinct from the [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) _statement_, where you must use a self-chosen iterator variable.

Comment: and let's imagine that I Get-Item three kind of file according to a -Include of three extension as in my question. How can I create an if, elseif, else to move the list retrieved by the Get-Item according to the extension of each file. I read somewhere that you can use -Like in if?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73522970/18023379