# Reorganize the files of a folder according to their extensions (jpg,mp3,mpeg) and check the duplicates

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to reorganize the files in a folder according to their extensions (jpg,mp3,mpeg) and check for duplicates to increment something to their name to allow manipulation. My goal is to redirect mp3 files to an audio document, mpeg to video and jpg to image.

```
function deplacer_dossier {

$AudioDoc = "C:\mestp\media\audio\"
$VideoDoc = "C:\mestp\media\video\"
$ImageDoc = "C:\mestp\media\image\"

    $files = Get-Item -Path C:\mestp\mesFichiers\* -Include *.jpg, *mp3, *.mpeg
        Foreach ($file in $files)  {
            if ($File -Like "*.jpg") {
                while(Test-Path -Path "$ImageDoc$files") {
                    $NewImageDoc = Join-Path $ImageDoc ($file.BaseName + "_" + $i + $file.extension)
                    $i++
                    $file | Move-Item -Destination $NewImageDoc 
                }
            }
            elseif ($File -Like "*.mp3") {
                while(Test-Path -Path "$ImageDoc$files") {
                    $NewAudioDoc = Join-Path $AudioDoc ($file.BaseName + "_" + $i + $file.extension)
                    $i++
                    $file | Move-Item -Destination $NewAudioDoc 
                }
            } 
            else {
                while(Test-Path -Path "$ImageDoc$files") {
                    $NewVideoDoc = Join-Path $VideoDoc ($file.BaseName + "_" + $i + $file.extension)
                    $i++
                    $file | Move-Item -Destination $NewVideoDoc 

            }
        }

}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to first group the matching files via [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object):

```bash
Get-Item -Path C:\mestp\mesFichiers\* -Include *.jpg, *mp3, *.mpeg | 
  Group-Object Extension |
  ForEach-Object {
    # Determine the file-type-specific destination directory.
    $destDir = @{ 
         '.jpg' =  'C:\mestp\media\image'
         '.mp3' =  'C:\mestp\media\audio'
         '.mpeg' = 'C:\mestp\media\video'
    }[$_.Name]
    # Move all files of the type at hand to the destination directory,
    # avoiding duplicates by suffixing the base file name with "_" 
    # followed by a sequence number.
    $_.Group |
      Move-Item -WhatIf -Destination { 
          $i = 0
          $suffix = ''
          while (Test-Path -LiteralPath ($destFile = Join-Path $destDir ($_.BaseName + $suffix + $_.Extension))) {
            $suffix = '_' + ++$i
          }
          $destFile
      }
  }
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>