# Compare multiple wildcard patterns in if statement on powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, wildcard, string-matching

How can i compare multiple wildcard patterns on a if statement?

```
if ($file.Name -like "*test*", "*.tmp")  
{
    # do something
}
```

Comment: `-like` is not a regex operator, it's a _wildcard_ operator. Are you hoping to match files that contain either or _both_ substrings? eg. are `something.tmp` and `test.zip` both matches, or does it need to be `something_test_something.tmp`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes, im trying to match something.tmp and test.zip separately

Comment: `if ($file.Name -like '*test*' -or $file.name -like '*.tmp')`

Comment: Looks like your expression gets converted to string `'*test* *.tmp'`

Comment: `$file.extension -in 'tmp','txt'` if we were just talking extensions

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **neither `-like`, the [wildcard matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like), nor `-match`, the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch), support an *array* of patterns** to match against, as of PowerShell 7.2.x:

- Having this ability (with *any one* of the patterns matching being considered an overall match) would be useful; [GitHub issue #2132](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2132) asks for it to be implemented in a future PowerShell (Core) version.
- While PowerShell currently reports no *error* when you try to use an array on the RHS, its **current behavior is virtually *useless***: the array is *stringified* to form a *single* string, which means that its elements are *joined with spaces*; that is, `$file.Name -like "*test*", "*.tmp"` is the same as `$file.Name -like "*test* *.tmp"`

However, **as a *workaround* you can use `-match` with a *single* regex pattern that uses *alternation* (`|`)** to match one of multiple values:

```bash
if ($file.Name -match 'test|\.tmp$') {
  # do something
}
```

Note:

- `-match` matches *substrings* by default, so there's no need for regex equivalents to the `*` [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) metacharacter.

  - Conversely, you need to *anchor* patterns if you want them to occur in a certain position, such as using `$` above to assert that subexpression `\.tmp` matches at the *end* of the string.
- [regexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions), which are much more powerful than wildcards, have many more *metacharacters* that may require *escaping with* `\`; in this case, metacharacter `.`, which matches *any* character, must be escaped as `\.` in order to be matched as a *literal* `.`

  - For *programmatic* escaping of (sub)strings to be interpreted *literally* in a regex, use [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape), e.g. `[regex]::Escape('.tmp')`, which yields `'\.tmp'`.

---

**If you prefer to stick with `-like`, you need *two* operations**, which you must join with [`-or`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Logical_Operators), as [js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654942/js2010) shows in a comment on the question:

```bash
if ($file.Name -like '*test*' -or $file.name -like '*.tmp') {
  # do something
}
```

If the number of patterns is large or not known in advance, use a *loop*, such as via the [intrinsic `.ForEach()` method]([intrinsic `.Where()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where))):

```bash
$patterns = '*test*', '*.tmp'  # Array of patterns
if ($patterns.Where({ $file.Name -like $_ }, 'First')) {
  # do something
}
```

---

Finally, it's worth noting that **[`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item)** and **[`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)** support **`-Include`** (and `-Exclude`) parameters that do **support *multiple* patterns** (unlike `-Filter`), so you may be able to *pre-filter* your files, without needing to examine their names later; e.g.:

```bash
Get-Item .\* -Include *test*, *.tmp
```

Unfortunately, **`-Include` and `-Exclude` are notoriously finicky**, except (mostly) when `-Recurse` is also used; e.g., using `Get-ChildItem . -Include *test*, *.tmp` would *not* work as intended - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375) for details.