# How To Delete Multiple Files After Matching Through REGEX Using CMD/PowerShell In Windows?

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, cmd, command-line

I have a folder including sub-folders in my **Windows PC** where I have multiple files of images with different dimensions with standard formatted names as shown below.

- **first-image-name.jpg**
- first-image-name-72x72.jpg
- first-image-name-150x150.jpg
- first-image-name-250x250.jpg
- first-image-name-300x300.jpg
- first-image-name-400x400.jpg
- first-image-name-1024x1024.jpg
- **second-image-name.png**
- second-image-name-72x72.png
- second-image-name-150x150.png
- second-image-name-250x250.png
- second-image-name-300x300.png
- second-image-name-400x400.png
- second-image-name-1024x1024.png

Now I want to delete all those image files that are of different sizes as shown in their name and should leave the original one only.

For that, I tried many queries as shared below but non of these are working...

### Windows PowerShell:

`Get-ChildItem $Path | Where{$_.Name -Match '.*[0-9]+x[0-9]+.\(jpg\|png\|jpeg\)$'} | Remove-Item`

### Windows CMD:

`find -type f -regex '.*[0-9]+x[0-9]+.\(jpg\|png\|jpeg\)$' -delete`

`find -name '.*[0-9]+x[0-9]+.\(jpg\|png\|jpeg\)$' -delete`

None of the above is working so let me know what I am doing wrong...??? Please remember I have to use it as recursive as I have many folders inside the main folder too.

Comment: You can try it without escaping the parenthesis for the grouping and the pipe for the alternation in powershell `.*[0-9]x[0-9]+.(jpe?g|png)$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird) has provided the crucial pointer in a comment:

- You **mistakenly `\`-*escaped* the following [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) metacharacters** in your regex, which causes them to be matched *as literals*: `(`, `)`, and `|`. Simply omitting the `\` would work.
- Conversely, **you neglected to escape `.` as `\.`**, given that you want it to be interpreted literally.

However, I suggest the following **optimization**, which *pre-filters* the files of interest and then matches only against each pre-filtered file's *base* name (`.BaseName`), i.e. the name without its extension:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $Path -Include *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png |
  Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '-[0-9]+x[0-9]+$' } |
  Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note:

- The [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) above needs no `.*` prefix, given that PowerShell's [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator looks for *substrings* by default.

  - Using character class `\d` in lieu of `[0-9]` is an option, although `\d` technically also matches digits *other* than the ASCII-range characters `0` through `9`, namely anything that the Unicode standard classifies as a digit.
- While use of `-Include`, which (unlike `-Filter`) conveniently allows you to specify *multiple* PowerShell [wildcard patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards), works as expected *in combination with `-Recurse`*, in the *absence* of `-Recurse` its behavior is counterintuitive:

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375) for details.