# How to have index variable increase in ForEach-Object?

Tags: arrays, powershell, pipeline, powershell-7.3

I have this strange observation:

I want to run an expression for as many times as there are files.

Yet, the following script always executes only **once**, no matter how many files are found by `Get-ChildItem`:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.png'), (Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.jpg') |
  Sort-Object -Property 'Name' |
  ForEach-Object -Begin { $idx = 0 } -Process { ++$idx; $idx; }
```

If I replace the expression with `$_`, all rows are returned as expected:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.png'), (Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.jpg') |
  Sort-Object -Property 'Name' |
  ForEach-Object -Begin { $idx = 0 } -Process { $_; }
```

Comment: `(...),(...)` creates a nested array with two "inner" arrays. You want `(...;...)`: `(Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.png'; Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.jpg') |...`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but that results in a syntax error: `(Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.png';Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.jpg') … Missing closing ')' in expression.` — Please note my update to my question.

Comment: Looks like PS is optimizing and since you are not using the loop variable it is exiting the loop.  Use you second method.

Comment: @AxD Sorry, there's a `@` missing from my previous comment: `@(Get-ChildItem ...; Get-ChildItem ...)` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out, **`(...), (...)` creates a *nested* (jagged) array**, which is not your intent (the [`,`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-) operator *constructs an array* from its operands, even if those operands are themselves arrays).

The **best way to provide output from *multiple* commands** as pipeline input is to use **[`&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks)**  (or **[`.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-)** , if you need the commands to run directly in the caller's scope) **with a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`)**, in which, as usual you can **separate commands with `;`**:

```bash
& { Get-ChildItem -Filter *.png; Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg } |
  Sort-Object -Property Name |
  ForEach-Object -Begin { $idx = 0 } -Process { ++$idx; $idx; }
```

This approach *streams* the command output, whereas use of [`$(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) or [`@(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) (which in this particular case can be used interchangeably) - `$(Get-ChildItem -Filter *.png; Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg)` or `@(Get-ChildItem -Filter *.png; Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg)` - *collects all output first* and *then* sends it to the pipeline.

---

An **simplified version of your command** that makes do with a *single* [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) call, using the `-Path` parameter's support for *multiple* wildcard patterns:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Path *.png, *.jpg |
  Sort-Object -Property Name |
  ForEach-Object -Begin { $idx = 0 } -Process { (++$idx) }
```

- `-Filter` is usually preferable, because it filters *at the source*, but it only supports *one* wildcard pattern; while `-Path`, which makes *PowerShell* filter the results, is noticeably slower, the overhead from *extra* `Get-ChildItem` calls may negate that advantage.

  - There's also `-Include` / `-Exclude`, which also filter on the PowerShell side, but, unfortunately, they do not work as one would intuitively expect: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375).
- Also note the use of [`(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) around `++$idx`, which causes the updated value to also be *output*.