# Move-Item throws error when attempting to move directory contents to subfolder within same directory

Tags: powershell

I have a folder containing files, folders, and a target subfolder. I'm trying to move all contents of the folder into the target subfolder (excluding the target subfolder) using Move-Item. When I do so I get an unexpected "does not exist" error for the target subfolder. Am I misusing the command? Is there another argument that achieves what I want?

```
PS C:\test> dir


    Directory: C:\test


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         6/14/2023   1:06 PM                anotherFolder
d-----         6/14/2023  12:50 PM                subfolder
-a----         6/14/2023  12:50 PM              6 ItemA
-a----         6/14/2023  12:50 PM              6 ItemB
-a----         6/14/2023  12:50 PM              6 ItemC


PS C:\test> Move-Item * -Destination subfolder -Exclude subfolder
Move-Item : Cannot move item because the item at 'C:\test\subfolder' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Move-Item * -Destination subfolder -Exclude subfolder
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Move-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

PS C:\test> dir


    Directory: C:\test


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         6/14/2023  12:50 PM                subfolder
```

Looks like the move succeeded but I would prefer to not get an error for simple move operation... if I try without the Exclude argument, I get a different error:

```
PS C:\test> Move-Item * -Destination subfolder
Move-Item : The parameter is incorrect.
At line:1 char:1
+ Move-Item * -Destination subfolder
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\test\subfolder:DirectoryInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveDirectoryItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

PS C:\test>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing a ***bug* in *Windows PowerShell***, which has been fixed in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md).

**Workaround**:

```
Get-Item * -Exclude subfolder | Move-Item -Destination subfolder
```

<sup>Note: To include *hidden* files and subfolders, add `-Force` to the `Get-Item` call.</sup>

- `Get-ChildItem *` would work too in this case, but `Get-Item *` works more predictably across various scenarios.
- Note that you *must* use `*` in order for the `-Exclude` parameter to work as intended (in other words: just `Get-ChildItem -Exclude subfolder` would *not* work), because of the counterintuitive way the `-Include` and `-Exclude` parameters are implemented - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375) for background information.