# Delete Files under certain Folders and Leave Folders Intact with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to clean up folders, keeping the folders, but removing the files. I do not want to delete anything in some folders though and cannot figure out how.  Here is what I have so far, but it deletes everything in each folder and also removes the 2 scripts on the first level. The ones I have marked with a red rectangle I need the script to ignore, the other folders I want the files deleted from.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\Tara.verity\Documents_Local\RemoveFilesFromFolders'  -Exclude "*.exe","*.config","assets", "Documentation" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {$_.Delete()}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `-Recurse` from the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) call, pipe the results to another `Get-ChildItem` call to ensure that *subdirectories* among the item in the target folders have *their* items enumerated (without being included in the output themselves), and pipe the results to [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item):

```bash
Get-ChildItem `
    -Path 'C:\Users\Tara.verity\Documents_Local\RemoveFilesFromFolders' `
    -Exclude *.exe, *.config, assets, Documentation |
  Get-ChildItem -Force |
  Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note:

- Even though your input path is a *literal* path and should therefore normally be passed via `-LiteralPath`, a *bug in Windows PowerShell* (since fixed in PowerShell (Core)) causes `-Include` and `-Exclude` to be *ignored* when combined with `-LiteralPath`

  - If you were to use `-Include` rather than `-Exclude` you'd have to additionally ensure that your `-Path` value *ends in `\*`* (or is just `*`), for the reasons explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375).
- Note that the enumeration via the second `Get-ChildItem` call includes any nested subdirectories, which are also removed by [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item)(the `-Recurse` switch prevents a confirmation prompt).

  - If you only want to remove the *files* from these directories, add `-File` to the second `Get-ChildItem` call.
  - If you want to remove all files from these directories *recursively* while *retaining nested subdirectories*, add `-File -Recurse`.

Comment: @taraloca: D'oh! Please see my update, which fixes the logic while still using `-Exclude` logic. Glad to hear that the `-WhatIf` tip helped.

Comment: @taraloca, I only used [`Push-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/push-location) and [`Pop-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/pop-location) when I thought it was necessary to provide all the paths to match as part of the `-Path` argument, to avoid repetition. With the `-Exclude`-based solution, this is no longer necessary, I removed them. In general, changing the current location in scripts is best avoided, because it affects the session globally.